# Is a good practice have a xsl file with templates like a repository of functions?

Tags: xslt

I want to use a tools.xsl so:

```
<xsl:template name="converFormat">
.
<xsl:template name="changeDate">
.
<xsl:template name="writeTable">
.
.
```

These templates are like common functions that will invoke by others xsl files using

```
<xsl:call-template name="converFormat">
```

Would it be a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It might be a good idea to put the named templates in a namespace, so you have something like this in the library stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template name="library:converFormat" 
              xmlns:library="http://example.com/xslt-library">
 ...
</xsl:template>
```

and the caller writes something like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="lib:converFormat"
                   xmlns:lib="http://example.com/xslt-library"/>
```

Putting the library templates into a namespace helps reduce the chance of name conflict with templates in the calling stylesheets; it sometimes also has the psychological effect of making the library seem like something you ought to provide documentation for.  Both of these are Good Things.